# setup.py with cv2 dependency installed via conda (conda-forge opencv)

Tags: python, opencv, pip, conda, setup.py

I'm trying to collect python code in a package `gnn_pylib` and install it in my conda environment. My package will require opencv, which has been installed in my conda environment via:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

I can run cv2 functions correctly, and I can call functions in the packages using cv2 functions successfully:

```
import gnn_pylib
gnn_pylib.show()
```

But when i try to install the package running `pip install -e .`
from the `gnn_pylib` directory I get the following error:

```
Collecting cv2 (from gnn-pylib==0.1)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from gnn-pylib==0.1) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cv2 (from gnn-pylib==0.1)
```

Is there something i am missing? should I some way inform `pip` but my `conda` opencv?

The package has the following structure:

```
gnn_pylib/
    gnn_pylib/
        __init__.py
        show.py
    setup.py
```

`__init__.py` is as follows:

```
from .show import foo
```

`show.py` is as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def foo():
    cv2.imshow("random", np.random.rand(10,10))
    cv2.waitKey()
    return
```

`setup.py` is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='gnn_pylib',
      version='0.1',
      description='General purpose python library',
      url='http://github.com/whatever/gnn_pylib',
      author='whatever',
      author_email='whatever@gmail.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['gnn_pylib'],
      install_requires=[
            'numpy',
            'cv2',
      ],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Comment: Exactly my problem right now, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `cv2` as the required package name instead use `opencv-python` since that's the name of the OpenCV bindings package available from PyPI. So your `setup.py` file will instead look like this (same as above with different entry for the OpenCV bindings package requirement):

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='gnn_pylib',
      version='0.1',
      description='General purpose python library',
      url='http://github.com/whatever/gnn_pylib',
      author='whatever',
      author_email='whatever@gmail.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['gnn_pylib'],
      install_requires=[
            'numpy',
            'opencv-python',
      ],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Comment: well, you still not answer the question on "setup.py with <something> dependency installed via conda "

Answer (score 0):

`@James Adams` answer the specific case for `cv2`, replacing with more compatible `opencv-python`.

However, if you still want to have dependencies install from `conda`, consider make a conda package.

See similar question with answer:

[setup.py with dependecies installed by conda (not pip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57821903/setup-py-with-dependecies-installed-by-conda-not-pip)

[Use 'conda install' instead of 'pip install' for setup.py packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330925/use-conda-install-instead-of-pip-install-for-setup-py-packages)

I cannot find answer with detail step-by-step and example yet. But hope it help.