# setup.py with dependecies installed by conda (not pip)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, conda, setup.py, transitive-dependency

I am working on an existing Python 3 code-base that provides a `setup.py` so the code is installed as a Python library. I am trying to get this internal library installed with its own dependencies (the usual data science ones e.g. `pandas`, `pyodbc`, `sqlalchemy` etc).

I would like to have this internal library to deal with these dependencies and assume that **if that library is installed, then all the transitive dependencies are assumed to be installed**. I also would like to have the Anaconda (`conda`) version of the package rather than the `pip` version.

I started with a `requirements.txt`, but moved quickly to this field in `setup.py`:

```
  install_requires=[
      "pyodbc>=4.0.27",
      "sqlalchemy>=1.3.8",
      "pandas>=0.25.1",
      "requests>=2.22.0",
      "assertpy>=0.14",
      "cycler>=0.10.0",
  ]
```

However when I run the installation process:

- either with `python setup.py install --record installed_files.txt`
- or with `pip install .`

I see that there is some `gcc` / C++ compilation going on that shows logs about Python wheels (I don't completely understand the implications of Python eggs and Python wheels, but AFAIK if `conda` is available then I should go with the `conda` version rather than eggs/wheels because then I don't have to take care of the C++ code underneath the Python code).

I really would prefer having `conda` to install these C++ blobs wrapped in some Python code as a libraries e.g. `pandas`.

- is it possible at all to have `conda` driving the installation process described in `setup.py` so I am not dealing with `gcc`?
- how can I make sure that other Python code depending on this internal library (installed via `setup.py`) is using the same (transitive) dependencies defined in that `setup.py`?

Regardless the installation method, how can I make sure that the dependencies for e.g. `pandas` are installed as well? Sometimes I see that `numpy` as a dependency of `pandas` is not installed when running `setup.py`, but I would like to avoid doing this manually (e.g. with some `requirements.txt` file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pip` doesn't know about `conda`, so you cannot build a pip-installable package that pulls in its dependencies from conda channels.

`conda` doesn't care about `setup.py`, it uses a different format for recording dependencies.

To install your code with `conda`, you should create a conda package, and specify your dependencies in a `meta.yaml` file. Refer to the documentation of "conda build" for details.

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html

Comment: I think this can get confusing because so many conda packages are basically wrappers around a `pip install` build script so lots of conda packages do have a `setup.py` in addition to a recipe. e.g. https://github.com/conda-forge/requests-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/meta.yaml

Comment: While this may have been accepted it is not an answer to the question in the title.  Change the title and I'll change my vote to up if appropriate.

Comment: @user3673 The title is chosen by the person asking the question, not by those writing answers.