# Use 'conda install' instead of 'pip install' for setup.py packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, setup.py

I want to install fastai using setup.py in a project. The nicest way, if I have a conda environment, is to use the conda install command `conda install -c pytorch -c fastai fastai`. Unfortunately, if I just add fastai as a requirement, it gets installed using pip, which I have experienced issues with.

Simply, is there a way to install fastai using conda a setup.py file (using the `conda install` command)?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `conda` package manager does not understand `setup.py`. As a result, one cannot install packages from `setup.py` with `conda`.

However, we can install libraries using conda with a `.yml` file. Typically, this is used to copy a `conda environment` across machines. More information about [creating environment file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274007/anaconda-export-environment-file) and [using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352841/how-to-update-an-existing-conda-environment-with-a-yml-file).